# how to exclude particular dependency package version from setup file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, setup.py

I've a small package that does not work on `torch v1.8.0` but it works fine on the new `v1.8.1` version and other older versions `v1.7.1` so want to exclude the `v1.8.0` version.

I could just set

```py
install_requires=[
    "torch>=1.8.1",
      ...
```

but the torch package size is huge and also want `mypackage` to work on the older versions of the torch.

I've tried

```py
install_requires=[
    "torch>=1.8.1,!=1.8.0,<=1.7.1",
       ...
```

but when installing the package with `pip install mypackage` getting the following error:

```py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch!=1.8.0,<=1.7.1,>=1.8.1 (from mypackage) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 0.4.1, 0.4.1.post2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch!=1.8.0,<=1.7.1,>=1.8.1 (from mypackage)
```

how can exclude the `v1.8.0` version? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can specify a minimum version and also exclude certain versions. Below, the minimum version is `1.0.0`. This should be set to a reasonable value depending on the project.

```
torch>=1.0.0,!=1.8.0
```

The issue with `torch>=1.8.1,!=1.8.0,<=1.7.1` is that it requests torch greater than or equal to 1.8.1 *and* less than or equal to 1.7.1. That is not possible, so pip cannot fulfill the request.

[PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) and [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) are relevant here.